# R - loop for 95% confidence interval for R squared - bootstrap

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I do not have much experience in `R`, so I may be asking for something obvious. I have a dataframe (`INs3`) with a variable in each column.

```
head(INs3)

Dependant <- (1280.75, 1317.70, 1166.35, 1663.10, ...)  
X1 <- (0.029, 0.033, ...)  
X2 <- (0.076, 0.78, ...)  
Xn
```

I’m trying to estimate the `95% confident interval` of `R squared` using `bootstrap`. I managed to write the code for doing the calculations with two variables.

```
boot.test <- boot(INs3,function(data,indices)                          
summary(lm(Dependant~X1,data[indices,]))$r.squared,R=100)

ci <- boot.ci(boot.test, type="bca")   
ci
```

> ```
> BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
> Based on 100 bootstrap replicates
>
> CALL : 
> boot.ci(boot.out = boot.test, type = "bca")
>
> Intervals : 
> Level       BCa          
> 95%   ( 0.0070,  0.6189 )
> ```

I would like to estimate the confidence interval pairing the variable “Dependant” with each one of the variables (`X1`, `X2`, etc.). My dataset has over `100000` variables, so I want to implement a loop to make all this calculations and storing them in a dataframe or a list. I have managed to produce a list storing a summary of data related to the `bootstrap`, but I am only interested in confidence intervals of `R squared`. In addition, I have not been able to fit a suitable function on the code below to estimate those confidence intervals.

```
test5 <- as.data.table(INs3)[, 
  list(MyFits = lapply(.SD[, -1, with = F], function(x) boot(INs3,function(data,indices) summary(lm(Dependant~x,data[indices,]))$adj.r.squared, R=100)))
  ]
```

Can anyone give me some advice on this issue? . Thanks!!